# How to find a minimal sum path on a grid

Tags: ruby

I have this problem when I have to get from the top left of a grid to the bottom right with the sum of all the number be the smallest possible.

Example Grid

```
131, 673, 234, 103,18
201, 96, 342, 965, 150
630, 803, 746, 422, 111
599, 720, 497, 121, 200
342, 456, 744, 37, 331
```

the out put of this should 2297.

I have no idea how to start this problem.

Thanks

Comment: You might look into this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I am not going to write out all the code for you but I would have two separate functions, one that would list out all of the possible routes and then the second would evaluate each route by getting the sum of that route.

For the time being think that there are only two options directions wise, down or right. So the first path is D,D,D,D,R,R,R,R the next path might be D,D,D,R,D,R,R,R. So on and so forth.

For each path come up with a method for adding those numbers together, whichever path is the lowest will be the answer.

Comment: This is an impractical way of solving the problem.  The number of paths increases exponentially with the size of the grid. It doesn't have too be very big before it would take a lifetime to enumerate all paths.

Answer (score 0):

@ArupRaksit is correct: it's a straightforward shortest-path problem.

Think of it as a directed network with each number representing a node. If you can move diagonally as well as right and down, the arcs would be `131->673`, `131->96`, `131->201`, `673->234`, `673->342`,`673->96`, `201->`96`,...,`200->331`,`37->331`. If you can only move right or down, exclude the diagonal pairs.

The length of each arc `f->t` ("from"->"to") is the value of `f`. For example, the length of `201->96` is `201`. Alternatively, you could make the length of each arc the value of the "to" node `t`. It makes no difference because all paths include the nodes at the origin and destination, `131` and `331`.

Then simply compute the shortest path from `131` to `331` using a shortest path algorithm (see the Wiki Arup references). It would take no time at all to solve, even for huge grids.